# Using the Robot Framework plugin, how to copy files outside the log folder into Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, robotframework

I am running Robot Framework tests through Jenkins, and the tests use a custom Python library to take screenshots, save them into a specific folder (that is not the log folder), and embed them into the log.  In the Jenkins job, I have a post-build action set to publish the Robot results, and I can get Jenkins to copy image files that are generated within the log folder, but I can't figure out how to copy image files that are generated outside the log folder.

The project's `%WORKSPACE%` is `d:\git\product\registration`

The directory of Robot output is `\log\patient_search` (the log directory is generated inside the registration directory)

The directory where the other images are generated is `d:\git\product\registration\verify\images`

If I put `*.png` into the "Other files to copy" box, Jenkins will copy any images within the `log\patient_search` directory and they embed correctly into the log.  What I have in that box now is `*.png,%WORKSPACE%\verify\images\**`, and I have tried using backslashes instead, using a relative path (`..\..\verify\images\**\*.png`), and various combinations of asterisks and slashes.  Those images always show as broken links in the log.

Are these paths wrong, or can this just not be done for files outside of the log folder?

Answer (score 0):

I believe Robot Framework plugin "Other files to copy" works only inside "Directory of Robot output". A workaround would be to create a build step where you execute a shell and copy files to Robot output directory.

Comment: Wouldn't copying the files still result in broken images in the logs, since the custom library writes to the log using the path to the images directory?